# Pull Titles from Wordpress by Category and Add to an External Site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rss, feed

I'm trying to pull titles of posts based on a specific category from our WordPress blog and have them display on our website.

I've tried using the Google Feed API. It worked in their code playground, but not on the actual site. I also tried a different category in the playground, which didn't work.

I need a jquery or javascript solution since it will be implemented into a .aspx page.

Any ideas?

Comment: what didn't work? you should be able to fetch the categories feed ( http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds#Categories_and_Tags) using Googles feed API ( https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide#hiworld)

Comment: I'm able to pull posts based on the category, but I was trying to find a way to pull just the titles. I ended up using display:hide to hide the rest of the content, but I thought there might be a more sophisticated way of targeting specific portions of posts.